# Null pointer Exception when clicking on the marker again in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to add marker when clicked on map or place selected through Search, and i'm also using GeoJson for creating multiple layers, but i'm **getting a null pointer exception when clicking on the marker again in Google Maps**.

Error message:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.tekraiders.wherehouse.wherehouse, PID: 7058
>                                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                           at
>   com.google.maps.android.data.Layer.multiObjectHandler(Layer.java:144)
>                                                                                           at com.google.maps.android.data.Layer.access$000(Layer.java:41)
>                                                                                           at com.google.maps.android.data.Layer$2.onMarkerClick(Layer.java:114)
>                                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$2.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzu$zza.onTransact(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bz.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:84)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.dd.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:292)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:242)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.m.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:4070)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.af.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:611)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.df.onSingleTapConfirmed(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:236)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.g.onSingleTapConfirmed(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:189)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.i.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:132)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
>                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                try {
                    int i = 0;

                    //Log.e("SahajLOG", " latlang > " + latLng + " " + layer.getBoundingBox().contains(latLng) + " " + layer.getBoundingBox().including(latLng));
                    String MarkerString = "location marked";


                    i = 0;
                    for (LatLngBounds bbc : latLngBoundsArray) {
                        Log.e("SahajLOG", "callad A1" + bbc.contains(latLng));
                        if (bbc.contains(latLng)) {
                            i++;
                            layer.addLayerToMap();
                            MarkerString = "Cyclone ZONE 1";
                        } else if (layer.isLayerOnMap() && i == 0) {
                            layer.removeLayerFromMap();
                        }
                    }


                    i = 0;
                    for (LatLngBounds bbc : latLngBoundsArray2) {
                        Log.e("SahajLOG", "callad A2" + bbc.contains(latLng));
                        if (bbc.contains(latLng)) {
                            i++;
                            layer2.addLayerToMap();
                            MarkerString = "Cyclone ZONE 2";
                        } else if (layer2.isLayerOnMap() && i == 0) {
                            layer2.removeLayerFromMap();
                        }
                    }


                    i = 0;
                    for (LatLngBounds bbc : latLngBoundsArray3) {
                        Log.e("SahajLOG", "callad A3" + bbc.contains(latLng));
                        if (bbc.contains(latLng)) {
                            i++;
                            layer3.addLayerToMap();
                            MarkerString = "Cyclone ZONE 3";
                        } else if (layer3.isLayerOnMap() && i == 0) {
                            layer3.removeLayerFromMap();
                        }
                    }


                    i = 0;
                    for (LatLngBounds bbc : latLngBoundsArray4) {
                        Log.e("SahajLOG", "callad A4" + bbc.contains(latLng));
                        if (bbc.contains(latLng)) {
                            i++;
                            layer4.addLayerToMap();
                            MarkerString = "Cyclone ZONE 4";
                        } else if (layer4.isLayerOnMap() && i == 0) {
                            layer4.removeLayerFromMap();
                        }
                    }

                    if (hashMapMarker != null) {
                        if (hashMapMarker.get("otherLocMark") != null) {
                            removeUpMaker("otherLocMark");
                            setUpMaker(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, "otherLocMark", MarkerString);
                        } else
                            setUpMaker(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, "otherLocMark", MarkerString);
                    } else
                        setUpMaker(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, "otherLocMark", MarkerString);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

and marker

```
private void setUpMaker(double currentLatitude,double currentLongitude,String Key,String title) {
    hashMapMarker = new HashMap<>();
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title(title));
    hashMapMarker.put(Key, marker);
    marker.showInfoWindow();
  //  Log.e("SahajLOG", "setUpMarker > " +marker +" key "+Key);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("I am here!"));
}
private void removeUpMaker(String Key) {
    Marker marker = hashMapMarker.get(Key);
    marker.remove();
    hashMapMarker.remove(Key);
    Log.e("SahajLOG", "removeMarker > " + marker + " key " + Key);
}
```

Comment: maybe adding your Marker related code...will be helpful to better understand the situation..

Comment: I could have just added the code. There was no need of a down vote.. :/

Comment: *Downvotes are Not From Me*  brother...

Comment: okay..could you help me out. The error what i think may be because of multi layers as in error `multiObjectHandler` is coming but I'm not sure.